# How to get container size with docker Docker SDK for Python

Tags: python, docker

It is possible to view the containers size by running:  `docker ps -s` or by `docker inspect -s <container_id>`.

I wanted to do the same thing with the [Docker SDK for Python](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=inspect#module-docker.api.daemon).

To get all the details for first container I run:

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
containers = client.containers.list()
print(containers[0].id)  
client_api = docker.APIClient(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock')
client_api.inspect_container(containers[0])
```

I am getting list with all the containers information but only the size is missing:

```
{
  'HostnamePath': '/var/lib/docker/containers/dd418d37b0ea82b8ec32b5619ce77b6d897c8a847a575c3ed21c4ddd20d06b3e/hostname',
  'Mounts': [],
  'HostsPath': '/var/lib/docker/containers/dd418d37b0ea82b8ec32b5619ce77b6d897c8a847a575c3ed21c4ddd20d06b3e/hosts',
  'MountLabel': '',
  'AppArmorProfile': 'docker-default',
  'ExecIDs': None,
  'Path': 'sh',
  'GraphDriver': {
    'Data': None,
    'Name': 'aufs'
  },
  'Image': 'sha256:caf27325b298a6730837023a8a342699c8b7b388b8d878966b064a1320043019',
  'Name': '/jovial_wiles',
  'ResolvConfPath': '/var/lib/docker/containers/dd418d37b0ea82b8ec32b5619ce77b6d897c8a847a575c3ed21c4ddd20d06b3e/resolv.conf',
  'Args': ['-c', 'sleep 1111111'],
  'NetworkSettings': {
    'Networks': {
      'bridge': {
        'Links': None,
        'EndpointID': '2fb132d452ef55076296360a41aa06bbd03e128860ac56d9ead773e94bd09f25',
        'MacAddress': '02:42:ac:11:00:03',
        'Gateway': '172.17.0.1',
        'IPAddress': '172.17.0.3',
        'GlobalIPv6PrefixLen': 0,
        'NetworkID': '3da3f680f6a93df9a27948669c9174304f69d1e649702568b909e8cbb4a1ddcf',
        'IPv6Gateway': '',
        'IPPrefixLen': 16,
        'IPAMConfig': None,
        'DriverOpts': None,
        'GlobalIPv6Address': '',
        'Aliases': None
      }
    },
    'SandboxKey': '/var/run/docker/netns/9a764461f582',
    'EndpointID': '2fb132d452ef55076296360a41aa06bbd03e128860ac56d9ead773e94bd09f25',
    'MacAddress': '02:42:ac:11:00:03',
    'Gateway': '172.17.0.1',
    'SecondaryIPAddresses': None,
    'GlobalIPv6PrefixLen': 0,
    'SandboxID': '9a764461f58297f4fbaf692773a917430cc66eefdb9e76921da1da2faacc7997',
    'Ports': {},
    'IPAddress': '172.17.0.3',
    'LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen': 0,
    'Bridge': '',
    'IPv6Gateway': '',
    'SecondaryIPv6Addresses': None,
    'IPPrefixLen': 16,
    'HairpinMode': False,
    'LinkLocalIPv6Address': '',
    'GlobalIPv6Address': ''
  },
  'Platform': 'linux',
  'State': {
    'Pid': 33888,
    'ExitCode': 0,
    'Dead': False,
    'OOMKilled': False,
    'Error': '',
    'StartedAt': '2019-03-14T09:09:30.488548343Z',
    'Restarting': False,
    'FinishedAt': '0001-01-01T00:00:00Z',
    'Status': 'running',
    'Paused': False,
    'Running': True
  },
  'LogPath': '/var/lib/docker/containers/dd418d37b0ea82b8ec32b5619ce77b6d897c8a847a575c3ed21c4ddd20d06b3e/dd418d37b0ea82b8ec32b5619ce77b6d897c8a847a575c3ed21c4ddd20d06b3e-json.log',
  'Driver': 'aufs',
  'Config': {
    'OnBuild': None,
    'Env': ['PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'],
    'Entrypoint': None,
    'StdinOnce': False,
    'Tty': False,
    'AttachStdout': False,
    'Domainname': '',
    'Labels': {},
    'Cmd': ['sh', '-c', 'sleep 1111111'],
    'User': '',
    'AttachStdin': False,
    'WorkingDir': '',
    'Hostname': 'dd418d37b0ea',
    'OpenStdin': False,
    'AttachStderr': False,
    'Image': 'alpine',
    'Volumes': None
  },
  'Id': 'dd418d37b0ea82b8ec32b5619ce77b6d897c8a847a575c3ed21c4ddd20d06b3e',
  'Created': '2019-03-14T09:09:29.746351911Z',
  'ProcessLabel': '',
  'RestartCount': 0,
  'HostConfig': {
    'Links': None,
    'IOMaximumIOps': 0,
    'Cgroup': '',
    'IOMaximumBandwidth': 0,
    'Ulimits': None,
    'CpusetMems': '',
    'CpuQuota': 0,
    'BlkioDeviceReadIOps': None,
    'BlkioWeightDevice': [],
    'UTSMode': '',
    'BlkioDeviceWriteIOps': None,
    'Devices': [],
    'CgroupParent': '',
    'VolumesFrom': None,
    'CpuShares': 0,
    'ContainerIDFile': '',
    'MaskedPaths': ['/proc/acpi', '/proc/kcore', '/proc/keys', '/proc/latency_stats', '/proc/timer_list', '/proc/timer_stats', '/proc/sched_debug', '/proc/scsi', '/sys/firmware'],
    'BlkioDeviceWriteBps': None,
    'NanoCpus': 0,
    'UsernsMode': '',
    'OomScoreAdj': 0,
    'ReadonlyPaths': ['/proc/asound', '/proc/bus', '/proc/fs', '/proc/irq', '/proc/sys', '/proc/sysrq-trigger'],
    'CpuPercent': 0,
    'DeviceCgroupRules': None,
    'Privileged': False,
    'MemorySwappiness': None,
    'ExtraHosts': None,
    'PidsLimit': 0,
    'PidMode': '',
    'IpcMode': 'shareable',
    'NetworkMode': 'default',
    'CapAdd': None,
    'MemoryReservation': 0,
    'AutoRemove': True,
    'Memory': 0,
    'GroupAdd': None,
    'ReadonlyRootfs': False,
    'DiskQuota': 0,
    'BlkioWeight': 0,
    'SecurityOpt': None,
    'PublishAllPorts': False,
    'ShmSize': 67108864,
    'CpuPeriod': 0,
    'MemorySwap': 0,
    'LogConfig': {
      'Config': {},
      'Type': 'json-file'
    },
    'CpuRealtimePeriod': 0,
    'PortBindings': {},
    'RestartPolicy': {
      'Name': 'no',
      'MaximumRetryCount': 0
    },
    'VolumeDriver': '',
    'CpusetCpus': '',
    'Isolation': '',
    'DnsSearch': [],
    'DnsOptions': [],
    'ConsoleSize': [0, 0],
    'Runtime': 'runc',
    'Dns': [],
    'CapDrop': None,
    'KernelMemory': 0,
    'Binds': None,
    'CpuCount': 0,
    'OomKillDisable': False,
    'CpuRealtimeRuntime': 0,
    'BlkioDeviceReadBps': None
  }
```

When I ran `docker inspect -s <container_id> | grep size` I saw that it appears in the field named `SizeRw` but I can't find it on the above information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This information is coming from the Daemon so I needed to run the following code:

```
info = client_api.df()
for container in info['Containers']:
    if 'SizeRw' in container:
        print(container['SizeRw'])
```